# Visual Studio Object Browser disregards XML comment formatting

Tags: visual-studio, formatting, xml-documentation, objectbrowser

In my .NET XML comments on methods and classes, I try to provide usage examples in `<example><code></code></example>` blocks.  When I use Sandcastle to generate a .chm documentation file using my XML documentation, it's always formatted nicely and respects the newlines in my `<code>` blocks.  However, when I browse the classes and methods in Visual Studio's Object Browser, everything runs together in one line and the font is all the same (no monospace for code).  Is this due to something I'm failing to do in my XML comments, or is the Object Browser just dumb?  I'm specifically using Visual Studio 2008 Team System.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Huh! Faced the same problem. I have "googled" it and found that it is "knowing bug" and team of vs2010 promised to solve this problem in next versions (service packs?).

Comment: Did you find a bug report on Connect? If so, please post the link. I'd love to vote for it, and I'm sure so would many of my peers here on SO!